# 2D Vector Plot MatLab With Wind Data (data is in structs)

Tags: matlab, struct, plot, 2d

I'm currently aiming to make a 2D vector plot of U and V directional wind. I have currently have a <1x2 struct> that has everything bundled into it. Within that <1x2 struct> are two <1x1 struct>s which pertain to U and V direction wind.

Within those <1x1 struct>s I have a field entitled "fltarray" which is a <262792x1 double> and that holds the velocity magnitude of the wind vector. In addition to that there is a field "bds" which contains a <1x1 struct> which holds a field "bindata" that has the value of a <262793x1 uint8> which I believe is the angle direction of the wind magnitude.

This setup is duplicated for the V-vector component (commonly called "i" component) of the wind vector.

Ideally I'm aiming to pair the directions of the magnitudes with the direction and then plot the U-V resultant vectors that result from the pairing.

I've tried to upload pictures, but apparently my reputation is not high enough >_<

Those pictures can be found: http://www.flickr.com/photos/bsarg-bassplayer/ at the front of that photo stream.
Thank you for any and all help relating to this!

Comment: U cant have i and j components and mag and direction. Either there is an i mag and a jmag or there is a magnitude and directions, because i indicates east and j indicates north?>

Comment: Do you know what that bds data section would be then? It's values max out at 244 and I can't seem to find great documentation on it. The bds data section is the <262793x1 uint8> which appears in both the U and V categories of windspeed values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once u have a 2 vectors U = x_component (size = n * 1) where n is the time vector &
V = y_component (size = n * 1) and t then its simple

```
f = figure(1);
axes

mags = sqrt(U.^2+V.^2);

max_mag = max(mags);

q = quiver(0,0,U(1),V(1))

set(gca,'xlim',[-1*max_mag-1 max_mag+1],'ylim',[-1*max_mag-1 max_mag+1])

hold all

for aa = 2:n
    set(q,'UData',U(aa),'VData',V(aa));
    pause
end
```